Error propagation in variance calculation
Let's assume that I have $n$ measurements $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ of a given quantity $X$, e.g. regression coefficients. Each $x_i$ has a corresponding standard error $SE_i$. I'd like to calculate $RMSE$ of $\mathbf{x}$ from $0$ and in the simplest case I'd write
\begin{align}
 RMSE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2}
\end{align}
However, this approach makes no use of the standard errors that could potentially provide a valuable additional information. Is there a way to take them into account?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance

Using a combined RMSE?

I suggest that you can consider that each measurement of the quantity $X$ provides the result $x_i$ with standard error $s_i$ ($SE_i$) following the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(x_i,s_i^2)$.
We suppose also that the measures are all independent to each other.
Therefore, the true value of $X$, estimated by the average of $n$ measurements $\hat X$, follows the normal distribution
$$\hat X\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 \right)$$
And so, the error of the estimation is
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2}$$
